# Print/Merge document .docx format download not working with sample civimail newsletter template

Tags: printmerge

The docx format and odt format are not working or showing blank document when a complex tempate or the default template is chosed "Sample Civimail newsletter template" itself is not working.

Comment: Might be similar to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2413 ?